# Calculate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2k}{3^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

I have solved it, but it does not match with the last part of solution. The logic is:
Let's consider complex series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2k + i\sin 2k}{3^k}$, imaginary part of which is exactly the series in question.

The complex series is a complex geometric series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k$, having $z = \frac{\cos 2 + i\sin 2}{3}$ (De Moivre's formula).

The geometric series in quesion is decreasing and hence its sum equals to:
$$\frac{1}{1-(\cos 2 + i\sin 2)/3}$$

The above is the sum including $k = 0$ which gives us $z= 1$. After subtracting it:
$$\frac{1}{1-(\cos 2 + i\sin 2)/3} - 1 = \frac{1 - 1 + (\cos 2 + i\sin 2)/3}{1-(\cos 2 + i\sin 2)/3} = \frac{\cos2 + i \sin 2}{(3- \cos 2) - i \sin 2} = \mbox{multiply nominator and denominator so to get rid of imaginary part in denominator} = \frac{3\cos2 - \cos^2 2 + i\cos2\sin2 - i\cos2\sin2 - \sin^2 2 + i 3\sin2}{(3-\cos 2)^2 + \sin^2 2} = \frac{(3\cos2-1)+i3\sin2}{(3-\cos 2)^2 + \sin^2 2}$$

The imaginary part of the latter gives us the answer to the series in question:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2k}{3^k} = \frac{3\sin2}{10 - 6\cos 2}.$$

**In the solution the last part is somehow simplified to $\dfrac{\sin 2}{4 - 2\cos 2}$.**

Am I missing something or is it just some typo in the final answer?

Comment: You need to subtract 1, because $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and you have $k=1,2,\dots$

Comment: thanks! i have also found another typo when simplifying the Geometric series sum. the answer is still not the same and is probably incorrect in the solution manual.

**PS:** the solution has been updated to take into account the comment above.

Comment: Your answer is right. BTW since you're only interested in the imaginary part there's no need to subtract the purely real $1$, which simplifies the sums a little.

Comment: @bag_dush, your answer $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2 k)}{3^k}=\frac{3 \sin 2}{10-6 \cos 2}$ is correct.  Your don’t have to bother about the real parts and directly write the imaginary part as the answer.